# Reassign Checked rows from one GridView to another

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that has a checkbox (inside TemplateField). I would like to grab all the selected rows and reassign them to a new gridview. Any ideas on how I can go about doing this?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'reassign them to a new gridview?' Do you have a 2nd gridview you'd like to populate with the checked-rows of the first one?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the easisest way to do it is to wrap the second grid in a separate grid. Assuming you have named the checkboxses the same id for your second grid, you can use jquery plugin to detect selection of the first grid's check boxes, loop through the results and set check boxes of your second grid inside that other div to "checked" since the names of the chck boxes match.

Something like that:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
                   $('#BaseDiv > input[name=checkboxlist]:checked').each(function() {
                      //TODO: Retrieve the checkboxes from the second div using the combination of second div id and search for it's children check boxes.
       });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

just fetch all the checked rows from the first gridview and add them into a datatable. Now assign this datatable to another gridview as datasource and bind it.